# Linux, dhclient: How to find out if my DHCP config is valid (without network interruptions)

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I work on a Linux system with "classical" network setup, i.e. there is no full featured configuration daemon running like NetworkManager. Most configuration is done by dhclient.

I need to detect situations where I have to re-run dhclient. (different subnet due to cable or network config changes). I want to run the check every 10 minutes without cutting existing connections.

What I basically need is an answer to questions like *Is my IP Adress and Gateway valid for the Network I am connected to?* or *If I would renew my DHCP Lease, would I gett the same IP again?*. To answer the first question, one could just ping some public IP like 8.8.8.8, but I need a solution that also works in big private networks I have no knowledge about. Even the default gateway might not always be pingable.

One I knew my ip is invalid I would do "dhclient -r eth0 ; dhclient eth0" to renew the lease. However, this disconnects me from internet for a short time, if I am already connected properly.

I found out that dhcping is a good tool to ask the DHCP server without actually using the result. However, I get strange results, which may even qualify for another question. It seems that dhcping only works well if I know the servers ip in advance, so there is a tool missing for the DHCP DISCOVER. (and using broadcast server adresses is unreliable)

I know that I can do hdcp discover with nmap, however, installing nmap is not a good idea due to security reasons.

Questions I'd like to ask:

- Is there a way to validate my configured ip in the context of the connected network?
- Is there a chance to have the dhclient lease renewed on demand?
- Are there tools doing a dhcp discover broadcast and printing the result?

**Addendum**:

Unlike the results of my first test, just calling *dhclient -v* does not solve my problem. To clarify this, my initial problem is dhclient running in a background mode (without actually renewing the lease all the time). Calling dhclient results in:

*dhclient(30887) is already running - exiting.*

This is not fully repoducable, though. Sometimes it succeeds. (This is why I first thought the -v option would make a difference, it does not)

So my question is: If I get this already running issue, although dclient is currently doing nothing, how to trigger a renewal for the background process?

(Rationale behind this is, that a DHCP client needs to bind to port 68. When this port is bound by the dhclient background daemon, another instance cannot be executed in foreground)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the first two questions is the same: use

```
dhclient -v eth0
```

(*-v* stands for verbose, not all Linux distros have it), instead of *dhclient -r eth0; dhclient eth0*. This shorter form **first** asks for a re-assignment of the current IP address, and then starts a negotiation with the router only if this cannot assign the requested IP address, either because it is taken already or because it is outside the gateway's DHCP range.

I suggest you use the *-v* flag so that you can see this exchange, it is quite explicit.

As for your third point, there is AFAIK no dry-run option for any dhcp client. If you really insist on that, however, you can do the following: set up a *macvlan* interface, and start a *dhcp* instance for this new interface:

```
ip addr flush dev eth0
ip link add link eth0 mac0 type macvlan mode bridge
dhclient -v mac0
```

At this point, you can see the configuration provided by the local DHCP server, network, netmask, gateway and DNS servers on the **new**, virtual interface. When you are done,

```
ip link del dev mac0
dhclient -v eth0
```

will restore **exactly** the configuration you had before, **if** the DHCP server can dish out your old IP address. Otherwise, you are stuck with a new one ;-) . All of this is trivial to script, really.

And, BTW, if your problem is the persistence of *ssh* connections, I suggest you check [mosh](https://mosh.org/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for this great and comprehensive answer! Its a bit confusing that dhclient changes behaviour just by adding the -v flag, but this is exactly what I need.

And btw, it is not about ssh, but I'm glad you mentioned mosh. This seems to be an interesting project.

Comment: @philipp Sorry for leading you into error : *dhclient* changes behavior when you drop the *-r* flag; the *-v* flag only displays the negotiation. When you do *dhclient -r eth0,; dhclient eth0* the second invocation cannot ask for a lease of its old IP address, because you have just relinquished it.

Comment: Thanks: indeed there is no difference, and this is still not the solution for my problem. I still get the "already running" message most of the time, which is my root problem. I added this to my question

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I found so far is using a dhcp discover implementation in python:

https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577649-dhcp-query/

Which is quite nice, as I already use python. But maybe I am still missing a simple solution and this is all overcomplicated.

**edit:** This did not really help. My main problem is that a dhclient background process is occupying port 68, which prevents any other process doing DHCP discovery, and I do not know any way to make the background process free it without dropping network config.